# PHP simplexml_load_file and ampersand (&) in contents

Tags: php, xml, ampersand

I'm using an XML file with PHP (simplexml_load_file) which has a TV program in it that is displayed in a site.

My problem started when the channel giving me that XML has an ampersand (&) inside the XML's contents like that:

```
<display-name lang="en_US">Crime & Investigation</display-name>
```

When simplexml_load_file tries to open the file we get an error saying the the ampersand is not allowed. When I edit the XML myself and change the ampersand to `&amp;` simplexml_load_file can load the file no problem.

I can't contact the channel to tell them to make the XML safe by using html entities, so is there a way to open somehow the file, read it's contents, change & to `&amp;` and then reopen it with simplexml_load_file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how is you xml tag declaration ? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: Exactly, it's <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: Did you tryed using <![CDATA[ TEXT HERE with & normal ]]> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms256076(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: The xml is provided directly from the channel, and then I read it and display it's contents to my site. I can't edit it directly and add <![CDATA[ TEXT HERE with & normal ]]> to it's contents. To see if the ampersand was to blame I just downloaded it from the channel and made a test from my computer.

But the file itself is stored at the channel server.

Comment: i did a way how can you solve the problem, if you can't change the xml file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't contact the channel to tell them to make the XML safe

It's not a question of making the XML safe, it's a question of making it XML. The current stuff they are sending you is almost certainly intended to be XML, but they have a bug in their code and if they are remotely service-oriented then they would want you to tell them about it.

Don't accept shoddy goods; don't accept corrupt data. Once you start trying to repair defects in what they send you you're running uphill on a down escalator: you never know what the next problem is going to be.

Comment: You're right about this. But I can't contact them. If I don't find a solution here I'll see what I can do to contact them somehow...

Comment: Any solution you find here will merely be trying to mend leaky plumbing with band aid / sticky plaster. It may postpone the disaster waiting to happen for a few weeks.